# Why Twitter button does not load if Twitter code is in a separate file

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I have three different ways to add Twitter code for loading Twitter button that seems almost identical to me, but for some reason only two of them do work.

Here is how I define Twitter button in HTML:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
```

Here is a fist method that works, just embed JavaScript code in the page:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

Here is a second way that works, put this function into a separate file and load this file on page load:

```
<script>
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
       // js/social.js just contains the same code that 
       // was in <script> tag in previous example
       $.getScript('js/social.js', function() {});
    });
</script>
```

But if I just include js/social.js file via  tag it doesn't work:

```
<!-- js/social.js here has the same content as in the previous example -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/social.js"></script>
```

and image does not load.

Could you explain what it the difference between those variations?

I am using Firefox 40.0.3

Comment: Where do you put the js/social.js on the page? header, body, footer?

Comment: In all three cases I put the definition at the end of <body> with all other scripts.

Comment: The content of js/social.js is the same content as your first example?

Comment: Yes, the code is identical in all 3 examples.